# Why can't I hear the login sound?

Tags: 11.04, sound, login

I am running Ubuntu 11.04 Natty and just noticed that I don't hear any login sounds. I checked the sound preferences and it shows that the Ubuntu sound theme is selected.
[image]

Also in the startup applications the gnome login sound is present. This can be seen below.
[image]

**Is this a bug? Are the login sounds included with Natty? If there are no sounds, can I remove it from the startup applications?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Try turning up the alert volume in sound preferences. This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

By clicking Edit button of Gnome Login Sound in Startup Applications Preferences, you should check if the path is correct and is a valid path.  If the path contains a regular wav file, it should work properly.

Edit: Of course, you can delete this option if you don't wanna.

Comment: The path shown in the startup is /usr/bin/canberra-gtk-play --id="desktop-login" --description="GNOME Login". Is this the same for you?